# Get attribute value from a selected item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a MVC application I have a list :

```
<ul>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="1"><form>...A..<form/></li>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="2"><form>...B..<form/></li>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="3"><form>...C..<form/></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get data-id property from the selected li ?

I have tried this code in Jquery:

```
  this.$list = this.find("ul").first(); 
  this.$list.on("click", "[data-action=\"open\"]", function (e) {

         var x = e.currentTarget.parentElement;//it brings me all the li elements , not just the one that was selected
         var elem=x.data('id');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :You have registered click event handler for `li`s under `ul`. So just read `$(this).data('id')` to get `data-id` of the clicked `li` instead of reading it from its parent element i.e. `e.currentTarget.parentElement;`

**Note**: - I have removed `this` in my code below as I don't have reference to it.

```js
var $list = $(document).find("ul").first(); 
$list.on("click", "li[data-action=\"open\"]", function (e) {
  var elemId =$(this).data('id');
  alert(elemId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="1"><form>...A..<form/></li>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="2"><form>...B..<form/></li>
 <li class="list-item" data-action="open" data-id="3"><form>...C..<form/></li>
</ul>
```